# NetBeans JPanel gradient background

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gradient

There are several posts on how to add a gradient to a JPanel however they all assume we're hard coding the JPanel from scratch. Can anyone explain how to add a gradient to a JPanel that was built using the NetBeans GUI builder? (I'm a Java newbie... more experienced with Processing, so if you don't mind answering as if I'm a nine year old...).

I have a JPanel called "Home" that I want to put a gradient on. In NetBeans, under the Customize Code menu option, I can see this:

Home.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 204, 255));

There are several posts with variations of this code here:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
            0, 0, Color.white,
            0, h, Color.black);

    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

But where do I put this, and how do I attach it to my Home panel? And what does g refer to?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You'll want to put the NetBeans code generation away for a while and experiment with coding Swing by hand until you understand the library, since the code generator can get in the way of this understanding. Once you are familiar with the library, then sure use the code generator if desired, but not til then. You first must gain an understanding of Swing fundamentals, such as "what does g refer to" (check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make your own panel class and extend JPanel. I have never used the NetBeans GUI builder to know if you can add custom components with it. `g` refers to the Graphics object that is a parameter to the method.

```
public class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(
                0, 0, Color.white,
                0, h, Color.black);

        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

Then just use GradientPanel instead of JPanel.

See the relevant tutorial if you want to understand the painting but you can more or less just copy and paste that code and use it:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: Do not dispose of a graphics context you did not create, this may actually prevent what you're being drawn from being rendered on some systems

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah you're right. Didn't even see all they did was cast it. Just copy and pasted. =/

Comment: You could make `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();` instead and add the `dispose` call, which would actually be a better solution ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Out of curiosity, why do you think that's technically better? Just to be safe because changes to the argument Graphics object are carried over to subsequent paint methods (paintBorder/paintChildren)? I personally always make a copy for that reason but have never heard that it was preferred.

Comment: Create a copy of the graphics context prevents any possibility that you will forget to reset the graphics context back to what it was before. The Graphics context is a shared context so it is used to paint all the other components.  Had a strange issue a while ago because one of the developers kept setting antialiasing but didn't reset it, meaning the you would get these funny paint updates as you moved the mouse over the screen :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer OK so essentially yeah. I knew the Graphics object passed in was not the same as the one returned from getGraphics but did not know it was shared. And the issue you describe is very similar to how I discovered the changes were passed on, although I was painting to a BufferedImage across a lot of different objects rather than in paintComponent. In retrospect it seemed like a pretty obvious error since I was passing the object around myself.

Answer (score 0):

The NetBeans GUI Builder does not want to use any constructor other than the default one without arguments. For this reason extensions of JPanel will be hard to use if they require arguments to constructors. Needs to override paintComponent(), and needs the default constructor defined. 
To use the code below ( adapted from above) create a folder in your project under "Source Packages" and add the class file below. drag and drop on Design canvas as from palette.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Color;
public class GradientPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();

        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.white, 0, h, Color.black);

        g2d.setPaint(gp);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        g2d.dispose();
    }
    public GradientPanel(){
   // added default constructor
    }
}
```